# Floating / Sliding UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

Im trying to create an interface for the iPad that basically has

- 3 UIViewControllers, all three next to each other
- One more **floating** viewController that lays "**above**" the other three view controllers. using swipe guestures, it would slide OVER the viewcontrollers to the other side.. exposing the view controller below it.
- Its been done in an app called iQuran HD for iPad.

I'm not sure where to start here, obviously i have to use container APIs, but beyond that I'm confused,

any ideas?

Comment: Read carefully the API doc for UIViewController and pay attention to the parts about adding sub-viewControllers.

Comment: i did, i was wondering more about a sliding viewcontroller OVER the three viewcontrollers